# Правильный подход к объявлению своей функции, описывающей DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, индексация, multi-index

Как правильно объявить свою функцию, описывающию DataFrame?

Имеется набор данных в Excel.
Написал отдельно набор функций, которые тем или иным образом подготавливают и обрабатывают загружаемые данные.

Выглядит примерно так:

```
instr = f'''
    Версия: {version}
    Предоставляет набор методов для загрузки и первичной обработки отчета из Ексель по объему инвестиций.
    В том числе:
    - prepare_df_from_excel(file) = подготовка датафрейма для дальнейших операций с использованием Pandas;
    - describe_year = возвращает описательную статистику полученного на вход диапазона
    - load_target_params = возвращает датафрейм (для удобства) с входными параметрами обработки'''
def prepare_df_from_excel(file):
    pass
def describe_year(df, _year = None):
    pass
def load_target_params(data=None):
    pass
```

Вопрос конкретно про функцию `describe_year`, представляющую из себя следующий код:

```
def describe_year(df, _year=None):
"""
    Возвращает описательную статистику полученного на вход датафрейма за заданный год
"""
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    _year = 2019 if _year is None else _year
    begin = f'{str(_year)}-01-01'
    end   = f'{str(_year)}-12-01'
    res = df.loc[idx[:, :, begin:end], :]
    return res.describe()
```

Сейчас использую как-то так:

```
file = "filename.xlsx"
df = prepare_df_from_excel(file)
describe_year(df, 2019)
```

Не могу придумать, как задать аргумент, чтобы была возможность передавать слайсы.
Например:

```
# выводим описательные статистики за один год
describe_year(df, 2019)
# выводим описательные статистики за диапазон лет: 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022
describe_year(df, [2019:2022])
# выводим описательные статистики за два года: 2019, 2022
describe_year(df, [2019,2022])
```

UPD:
обработанный DataFrame имеет следующий индекс:

```
> MultiIndex([...], names=['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия', 'Агрессивный НДС', 'Дата инвестиции'], length=73012)
># 'IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия' - str
># 'Агрессивный НДС' - bool
># 'Дата инвестиции' - Timestamp
```

UPD2: код для теста:

```
test = {
    'Расчет': ('00000639617', '00000675306', '00000675306'),
    'IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия': ('02ab9164', '02ab9164', '02ab9164'),
    'Агрессивный НДС': (True, True, True),
    'Дата инвестиции': ('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'),
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test)
df_test['Дата инвестиции']  = pd.to_datetime(df_test['Дата инвестиции'], dayfirst=True)
df_test = df_test.set_index(['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия', 'Агрессивный НДС', 'Дата инвестиции'])
df_test.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)
segments.ext_describe_year(df_test, slice(2019))
```

Comment: Если дата в вашем датафрейме имеет тип datetime, то можно все существенно упростить.

Comment: Датафрейм имеет мультииндекс следующих типов: [str, bool, Timestamp]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def describe_year(df, dt_start='2019', dt_stop=None):
    if isinstance(dt_start, int):
        dt_start = str(dt_start)
    if dt_stop is None:
        dt_stop = str(dt_start)
    if isinstance(dt_stop, int):
        dt_stop = str(dt_stop)        
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    res = df.loc[idx[:, :, dt_start:dt_stop], :]
    # return res.describe()
    return res
```

тесты:

```
In [10]: describe_year(df_test, 2020)
Out[10]:
                                                              Расчет
IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9164                True            2020-01-01       00000675306

In [11]: describe_year(df_test, 2019)
Out[11]:
                                                              Расчет
IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9164                True            2019-01-01       00000639617

In [12]: describe_year(df_test, 2019, 2020)
Out[12]:
                                                              Расчет
IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия Агрессивный НДС Дата инвестиции
02ab9164                True            2019-01-01       00000639617
                                        2020-01-01       00000675306
```

Comment: Вызов функции при этом должен быть таким: describe_year(df, slice(2019))?

Comment: Ловлю ошибку: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [2019] of <class 'int'>

Comment: @АлексСеркин, можете привести в вопросе код для создания небольшого DF с мультииндексом для воспроизведения ошибки?

Comment: Пробую изо всех сил :)

Comment: @АлексСеркин, убрал `slice()` - это значительно упростило код функции...

Comment: в 117-м выводе хочу получить только одну строку с 2019-м годом. поэтому немного изменил

Comment: @АлексСеркин, `describe_year(df_test, dt_stop=2019)` ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103643/discussion-between---and-maxu).